# Java- creating a String object but assigning otherwise afterwards

Tags: java

I have a question concerning establishing String objects in Java.

Let's say I create a String object like this:

```
String mystring=new String();
```

Now, if I take this String object and assign to it a string like this:

```
mystring="abc";
```

What exactly happened here? Is `mystring` addressed exactly to the original object or is it a different object? Like `String mystring;` is the short-hand for `String mystring=new String();` what could `mystring="abc";` stand for?

Comment: In Java `String mystring;` is **not** a short-term for `String mystring = new String();`. It's just a declaration of variable without  any assigment, not even `null`. You can't do anything with such a thing except for assigning a value for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String mystring = new String();
```

creates a new `String` object and assigns the value of its reference to the variable `mystring`.

So

```
Variable                       Heap
--------                       ----    
mytring --------------------->  "" // an empty String object
```

Then you do

```
mystring="abc";
```

This assigns the value of the reference to the `String` object `"abc"` to the variable `mystring`. So

```
Variable                       Heap
--------                       ----    
mystring ------------------->  "abc"   
                                "" // will be garbage collected at some point
```

A variable does not change. The object it's referencing or the reference itself can change.

> Like String mystring; is the short-term for String mystring=new
>   String();

No `String mystring;` is a variable declaration. When that line is executed, the variable `mystring` is declared but not initialized.

On the other hand, `String mystring = new String()` both declares and initializes the variable `mystring`.

> for what could mystring="abc"; stand for?

That is an assignment expression, assigning the value of the reference to the `String` object `"abc"` to the variable `mystring`.

It's also important to understand that Strings are immutable. Once you create a `String` object, you cannot change it. For example, in the following code

```
String name = "user3133542"; // cool
name = "some other value";
```

You are not changing the object that `name` is referencing, you are creating a new object and assigning its value to the variable `name`.

[The `String` API does not provide any methods to change its value.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) We therefore call it **immutable**.

Consider going through the [Java `String` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Also, before you ask your next question, read this

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Could you also point out that strings are immutable, and that changing the value of mystring will create a new object?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `mystring` with `mystring="abc";` It is not the exactly to the original object at all. The `mystring` is a variable not object.